# Xamarin Forms splash image aspect ratio on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

I'm trying to resize a tall image for Android splash screen (iOS works OK) in Xamarin Forms app. I want to keep the aspect ratio but it gives me blank spaces on sides or the image is squashed when the view is filled.

I have tried multiple options which I found here but none of them work for me (crop, fit, center, scale, gravity, etc..).

This is my last try (mix of multiple answers):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
            <bitmap
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/splash"
                android:tileMode="disabled"/>
     </item>
     </layer-list>
```

...and it gives me correct aspect ratio but also blank spaces.
What's the correct solution to fill the screen horizontally without losing the aspect ratio?

[image: sample]

Comment: Are you sure this is Xamarin.Forms? Your sample code is native Android XML.

Comment: yes, the app is in Xamarin.Forms but it's under Android section so it will be the same as native Android XML

Comment: Did you try using [`center_inside`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType#summary) instead of `fit_center` on the `scaleType`?

Comment: yes, I have tried all scaleType and Gravity options. It give me the same output always - black spaces on side or full screen image but wrong aspect ratio.
..so there is an option which I haven't tried yet or it's no possible.

Comment: Did you get a solution on this? I am hitting the same issue.

Comment: No, I think the best solution for Android was to use gradient or solid colour as a background to match logo background colour

Answer (score 0):

You can combine gravity attributes to combine auto fill effects.

My code for exemple is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal|fill_vertical"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

This add possibilities and may give you one which suits your needs.

An other possibility could be something like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:width="1200px"
        android:height="2200px">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Width and height corresponding to image size